# How to handle full-column ranges in UDF?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, optimization, excel-dna

I developed an addin for Excel using Excel DNA. I declared an UDF that accepts a range as input, casts the `ExcelReference` to `Range` and uses the enumerator from `GetEnumerator` to collect all cells values in a `List` for further processing and then writing outputs to another range.

As a test, I tried passing an entire column to the function (`A:A`) and everything froze because of the enumerator keeping enumerating empty cells after the last one with value.

Is there a faster way to detect a full-column Range and to get all its cells that are not empty?

For now I am using this code but it is incredibly slow in the above-mentioned case.

```
            Dim ue = inputRange.GetEnumerator    
            Dim L As New List(Of String)

            Do
                If ue.MoveNext Then
                    Dim c As Range = ue.Current
                    Dim V As String = c.FormulaLocal
                    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(V) Then Continue Do
                    L.Add(V)
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
```

I am going to use the following workaround, but I'd like to prevent this at the root.

```
            Dim ue = inputRange.GetEnumerator
            Dim counter as integer=0
            Dim L As New List(Of String)
            Do
                If counter>10 Then Exit Do
                If ue.MoveNext Then
                    Dim c As Range = ue.Current
                    Dim V As String = c.FormulaLocal
                    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(V.Trim) Then
                        counter = counter + 1
                        Continue Do
                    End If
                    L.Add(V)
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much faster to get all the values in one go from the `ExcelReference`, instead of getting a COM `Range` object.

Either remove `AllowReference=true` from the argument (then you'll get the value directly) or get the value from the `ExcelReference`:

```
object value = inputRef.GetValue();

if (value is object[,])
{ 
    object[,] valueArr = (object[,])value;
    int rows = valueArr.GetLength(0);
    int cols = valueArr.GetLength(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {    
            object val = valueArr[i,j];
            // Do more here...
        }
    }
}
```

If a cell is empty, the object you get will be of type ExcelEmpty. You can ignore these it you're not interested in empty cells.

Another approach is to use the C API to get the used range for the sheet, and intersect that with your `ExcelReference`. One disadvantage is that this requires your function to be marked `IsMacroType=true`, which (together with `AllowReference=true`) has the side effect of making your function volatile.

Code that shows how to do this is here: https://gist.github.com/govert/e66c5462901405dc96aab8e77abef24c

Comment: Thanks again! I used that Gist to upgrade my function: I was already using both `IsMacroType` and `AllowReference` so that code did fit in perfectly! :D